# CSS Invisible radio button but highlight wrapping div

Tags: css

The following HTML is being generates  radio_buttons as selectors from an image label

```
<div class='small-2 columns buttonselector'>
  <label for="content_ki_id_1">
    <input class="invisi-selector" type="radio" value="1" name="content[ki_id]" id="content_ki_id_1" />
    <img src="/assets/circle.svg" />
    <div></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

The CSS properly makes the radio button invisible, but there is a gap in handling the wrapper and its visibility on radio_button selected

```
.buttonselector > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.invisi-selector {
    opacity: 0;
}
.invisi-selector:checked + div {
    border-color: #ba53ad;
    border-width: 4px;
}
```

the wrapper cannot logically take the selector's class for it would be invisible.  How can the checked action be binded to the wrapping div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't, but you can use absolute positioning to make it look like it is.

```css
.buttonselector>label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.invisi-selector {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.invisi-selector~div {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.invisi-selector:checked~div {
  border: 4px solid #ba53ad;
}
```

```html
<div class='small-2 columns buttonselector'>
  <label for="content_ki_id_1">
    <input class="invisi-selector" type="radio" value="1" name="content[ki_id]" id="content_ki_id_1" />
    <img src="/assets/circle.svg" />
    <div></div>
  </label>
</div>
```